# I can't figure out how to get these color variables to work in the draw function

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have been trying to use built-in functions in p5.js but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, the col variable won't assign to moon.brightness rather the moon is always white when I preview it, I assigned my variables col and dor before the setup function and called them in the setup function before I initialised the Moon variable, at a total loss here, new to using p5.js so any help about where I am going wrong would be appreciated

```js
var groundHeight;
var mountain1;
var mountain2;

var tree;

var moon;
var sun;
var darkness;
var brightness;
var col;
var dor;

function setup() {
  cnv = createCanvas(800, 600)
  //set the groundHeight proportional to the canvas size
  groundHeight = (height / 3) * 2;

  //initalise the mountain objects with properties to help draw them to the canvas
  mountain1 = {
    x: 400,
    y: groundHeight,
    height: 320,
    width: 230
  };
  mountain2 = {
    x: 550,
    y: groundHeight,
    height: 200,
    width: 130
  };

  //initalise the tree object
  tree = {
    x: 150,
    y: groundHeight + 20,
    trunkWidth: 40,
    trunkHeight: 150,
    canopyWidth: 120,
    canopyHeight: 100
  };

  //initalise the sun
  sun = {
    x: 150,
    y: 70,
    diameter: 80

  };

  col = (150, 200, 255)
  dor = (255, 255, 255)
  //TASK: intialise a moon object with an extra property for brightness
  moon = {
    brightness: col,
    x: 700,
    y: 70,
    diameter: 80
  };


  //set the initial darkness
  darkness = {
    x: 800,
    y: 600,
    light: col
  };
}

function draw() {
  //TASK: update the values for the moons brightness, the sun's position and the darkness.
  //You can either map this to the mouse's location (i.e. the futher left the mouse is the more daylight) or you can just change the values gradually over time.

  //draw the sky
  background(150, 200, 255);
  noStroke();

  //draw the sun
  fill(255, 255, 0);
  ellipse(sun.x, sun.y, sun.diameter);
  sun.y = map(mouseX, 0, 800, 70, 630)

  fill(moon.brightness)
  ellipse(moon.x, moon.y, moon.diameter);
  moon.brightness = map(mouseX, 0, 800, col, dor);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. In JavaScript the expression `(1, 2, 3)` does not create a an array, or a vector, or a tuple, or anything that could be used to represent a color. The comma operator evaluates the expression on the left, and the regardless of the value of that expression, it evaluates an expression on the right.
2. The p5.js [`map()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/map) function does not work with colors, it only works with numbers. If you're working with colors you need to use [`lerpColor()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/lerpColor)

```js
var groundHeight;
var mountain1;
var mountain2;

var tree;

var moon;
var sun;
var col;
var dor;

function setup() {
  cnv = createCanvas(800, 600)
  //set the groundHeight proportional to the canvas size
  groundHeight = (height / 3) * 2;

  //initalise the mountain objects with properties to help draw them to the canvas
  mountain1 = {
    x: 400,
    y: groundHeight,
    height: 320,
    width: 230
  };
  mountain2 = {
    x: 550,
    y: groundHeight,
    height: 200,
    width: 130
  };

  //initalise the tree object
  tree = {
    x: 150,
    y: groundHeight + 20,
    trunkWidth: 40,
    trunkHeight: 150,
    canopyWidth: 120,
    canopyHeight: 100
  };

  //initalise the sun
  sun = {
    x: 150,
    y: 70,
    diameter: 80
  };

  // FIXED: Use the color function to create a p5.Color object from R G and B components
  col = color(150, 200, 255)
  dor = color(255, 255, 255)
  //TASK: intialise a moon object with an extra property for brightness
  moon = {
    brightness: col,
    x: 700,
    y: 70,
    diameter: 80
  };
}

function draw() {
  //TASK: update the values for the moons brightness, the sun's position and the darkness.
  //You can either map this to the mouse's location (i.e. the futher left the mouse is the more daylight) or you can just change the values gradually over time.

  scale
  //draw the sky
  background(150, 200, 255);
  noStroke();

  //draw the sun
  fill(255, 255, 0);
  ellipse(sun.x, sun.y, sun.diameter);
  sun.y = map(mouseX, 0, 800, 70, 630)

  fill(moon.brightness)
  ellipse(moon.x, moon.y, moon.diameter);
  // FIXED: when interpolating between two colors, use lerpColor instead of map
  moon.brightness = lerpColor(col, dor, mouseX / width);
}
```

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  transform: scale(0.25);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot for the help, I was confused at first but looking at your comments in the code, I understood it well now :) will continue to learn more. Thanks again.